# Turn array into independent function arguments - howto?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I want to use values in an array as independent arguments in a function call. Example:

```
// Values "a" and "b"
$arr = array("alpha", "beta");
// ... are to be inserted as $a and $b.
my_func($a, $b)
function my_func($a,$b=NULL) { echo "{$a} - {$b}"; }
```

The number of values in the array are unknown.

Possible solutions:

1. I can pass the array as a single argument - but would prefer to pass as multiple, independent function arguments.
2. `implode()` the array into a comma-separated string. (Fails because it's just one string.)
3. Using a single parameter:

   ```
   $str = "'a','b'";
   function goat($str);  // $str needs to be parsed as two independent values/variables.
   ```
4. Use `eval()`?
5. Traverse the array?

Suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "The number of values in the array are unknown." -- are they at least known to match the function signature's arg list?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This question is fairly old but there is finally more direct support for this in PHP 5.6+:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new

```
$arr = array("alpha", "beta");
my_func(...$arr);
```

Answer (score 26):

if I understand you correctly:

```
$arr = array("alpha", "beta");
call_user_func_array('my_func', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try list()

```
// Values "a" and "b"
$arr = array("alpha", "beta");
list($a, $b) = $arr;
my_func($a, $b);

function my_func($a,$b=NULL) { echo "{$a} - {$b}"; }
```

Comment: Not *technically* correct (call_user_func_array is how you are supposed to do this type of behavior, but this is very clever. +1

Comment: Good suggestion. You can then use a standard function call (without call_user_func_array) which keeps the code clean. The only pitfall is that list requires you to hard-code the arguments ... list($a, $b) ... while I don't the number of array values in advance.

Comment: I was thinking about `list()` when I was looking this question up, but it doesn't allow for an infinite amount of parameters, does it?

Comment: The number of elements in the array is unknown, so it is not a universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [call_user_func_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). It works wonders (and even with lambda functions since PHP 5.3).