# ruby convert array into function arguments

Tags: ruby, arrays, function, arguments

Say I have an array. I wish to pass the array to a function. The function, however, expects two arguments. Is there a way to on the fly convert the array into 2 arguments?
For example:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3]
a.slice(b)
```

Would yield an error in Ruby. I need to input `a.slice(b[0],b[1])` I am looking for something more elegant, as in `a.slice(foo.bar(b))`
Thanks.

Comment: Same question: [Sending elements of an array as arguments to a method call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4552552/1494454)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can turn an `Array` into an argument list with the `*` (or "splat") operator:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3] # => [2, 3]
a.slice(*b) # => [2, 3, 4]
```

#### Reference:

- [Array to Arguments Conversion](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion)

Answer (score 101):

Use this

```
a.slice(*b)
```

It's called the splat operator