# Pass in array as separate arguments in PHP

Tags: php

I've got an array like this

```
array('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
```

Does anybody know how I would pass each item into a function seperately?

EG:

```
hello_world('item1', 'item2', 'item3');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467350/turn-array-into-independent-function-arguments-howto

Comment: That didn't appear in any search results I received.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing an Array as Arguments, not an Array, in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744145/passing-an-array-as-arguments-not-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hello_world($array[0], $array[1], $array[2])
```

or

```
call_user_func_array('hello_world', $array)
```

http://php.net/call_user_func_array

Comment: Thank you! `$array[0] ...` etc wouldn't help here as it needs to be dynamic. I'm passing items from the URL into the function so with `/MyAction/hello/world` and `MyAction($item1, $item2)`: `$item1` would be hello and `$item2` would be world

Answer (score 4):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
call_user_func_array('func',$myArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array_map` function can help you http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-map.php

Comment: How can `array_map` help here?

Comment: Using array_map, it tells the function you want to apply to each item in the array. It's what I've understood that Andy needs.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the question. Whats the difference with call_user_func_array function?

Comment: I do not agree with the negative that has been given to my answer. Is a valid response based on the vision interprets the question.

Comment: I wanted to pass the array into the function. Not map each of the arrays values to the output of the function.