# Pass array to a function as individual arguments

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to pass a single array as separate arguments (parameters) to a function?

Given the following super simplified example:

```
Func<int, int, int> sum = (int a, int b) => { return a + b; };
// sum(1, 2); This would work and return 3
sum([1,2]); // This is how I would like to call it
```

Is there a way to make last line work?

Note: I know that you could make a delegate take a single `int[]` as an argument, but in my real use case modifying a delegate is not possible.

Note 2: In real use case parameters are **not** of the same type. It could be a mixture of `int`, `string`, `object`, etc.

If it helps, in PHP this could be achieved with `call_user_func_array()`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285481/pass-in-array-as-separate-arguments-in-php)

UPDATE:
Real use case is that I want to have a single function that receives a delegate and all required parameters. So instead of having to write out all different cases like below:

```
public void OneParam<T1, TOut>(Func<T1, TOut> func, T1 p1)
{
    // Do some fancy stuff before calling
    func.Invoke(p1);
}

public void TwoParam<T1, T2, TOut>(Func<T1, T2, TOut> func, T1 p1, T2 p2)
{
    // Do exact same some fancy stuff before calling
    func.Invoke(p1, p2);
}
```

I would like to have just a single function that takes any delegate with any amount of parameters and then eventually to be able to pass those parameters into a delegate.

TL;DR answer: As per @gunr2171 answer this is not possible. I wanted the opposite of `params`, which is not achievable. This probably make sense as C# creators also had to type out all different delegates with different amount of parameters manually as well.

Comment: C# does not have that functionality.

Comment: @gunr2171 It does, but only for `params` parameters - oh, and via `MethodInfo.Invoke` too.

Comment: @Dai `params` lets you pretend a series of individual values is an array, not pretend an array is a series of individual values.

Comment: @Dai is not this another way around i.e.  `a, b -> array`? =)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't allow you to have the discreet, named parameters `int a, int b` shown in the example.

Comment: Do you have an actual use case?

Comment: `sum(array[0], array[1])`

Comment: If the example you've shown is not representative of your actual use case, then *provide an example that is in fact representative of your use case*.

Comment: Could this be an XY problem?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel updated with actual use case

Comment: Could you use a single instance of ~some~ Class instead of loads of parameters?

Comment: Not only is this not currently possible. This can NEVER be done with a statically typed language like C#. You might be looking for the Tuple type. Duck type languages often conflate arrays with tuples.

Comment: Take a look at some of the answers to this question.  It may give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47815660/does-c-sharp-7-have-array-enumerable-destructuring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, C# does not have the functionality you are desiring. If your method has two parameters, you must call it with two parameters. A collection that has (or, "might have") two elements only counts as a single parameter.

Remember that there is no "array literals" in C#, so the compiler can't guarantee a collection has a particular length at compile-time.

---

C# has the `params` keyword. This is the *opposite* of what you're trying to do. It allows you pass in individual values when you *call* the method, but those values are treated as a *single collection* within the method.

```
void MyMethod(params int[] values) {
  // values is [ 1, 2, 5 ]
}

int someIntVariable = 5;
MyMethod(1, 2, someIntVariable);
```

You're looking for the reverse of that.

---

You *could* do something with reflection, at the cost of only being allowed *indirect* calls. You'd need to make a wrapper method to call the method on your behalf. In this example, I'm not doing any sort of validation, and types are strictly `int`s.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = Execute(Sum, new[] { 4, 5 });
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    // prints "9"
}

public static int Sum(int a, int b) => a + b;

public static int Execute(Func<int, int, int> method, ICollection<int> values)
{
    // optional: validation of values length
    return (int)method.DynamicInvoke(values.Cast<object>().ToArray())!;
}
```

However, of course, this only works if you are ok with making and calling this wrapper method. You're not calling `Sum` directly. If the end methods you'd like to execute vary in type and parameter count, you'll also need to adjust accordingly.

Probably the biggest disadvantage with this approach is that you lose compile-time guarantees that you are providing your methods with the correct number of parameters.

---

In my opinion, the sane thing to do here is extract the elements that you want from the collection to serve as individual parameters.

```
int[] values = new[] { 4, 5 };
Sum(values[0], values[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
var result = (int)sum.DynamicInvoke(new Object[]{1,2});
```

Be aware if arguments mismatch, you will get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

If input array is a mixture of different types then a good way is to use `params` like below

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HandleDifferentItems(new object[] {1,2,"three", 4});
    }

    static void HandleDifferentItems(params object[] args)
    {
        foreach (var item in args)
        {
            if (item is int)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Integer :" + item);
            }
            else if(item is string)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("string :" + item);
            }
            else if(item is SomeClass)
            {
                 //Handle some class
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `params` is the _opposite_ of the OP's intentions.